# User changes folder name in SP 2013 and link doesn't work?

Tags: folder, links

This might be a simple one, but has created a folder with various files, puts a link to it in an email, but if they change the name of the folder the link doesn't work. I thought that links in SP 2013 were dynamic and linked to the files even if the folder name was changed?

Answer (score 0):

**You can enable document ID service and configure it**.

SO new documents in the site collection will automatically be assigned new IDs. And it will track items regardless of their location or the name of folder in which document is present.

Refer this link - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-unique-Document-IDs-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984